# Swagger italicizing quotes

Tags: c#, swagger

Following remarks in the XML comments section in my code show up in Swagger -

```
    /// <remarks>
    ///    {
    ///     "your_val": "1a",
    ///     "member": "Test"       
    ///    }      
    ///</remarks>
```

I am noticing that the last value (in this case `Test`) always has italicized quotations (Red arrow). Does anyone know how to change it to be regular quotes? For example, like they are for 1a (Blue arrow).

[image]

Comment: But why you are using remarks in order to display the request view model or the response, the remark tag is used to add information about a type, supplementing the information specified with <summary>. This information is displayed in the Object Browser window. So <summary> is for a compact description of the element and <remarks> is for the full description.

Comment: You could use the annotation:
[ResponseType(typeof(YourResponseViewModel))]
Could you give more details... it is a response or a parameter?

Comment: @JaderOliveira Those parameters are for the request. I want to provide that in Swagger, so testers know how to make the request. Its meant to be an example request object, so they know how to construct the request with their own data.

Comment: I found a fix for your problem. Please, have a look in my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Add a **remarks** element to the Create action method documentation. It supplements information specified in the **summary** element and provides a more robust Swagger UI. The **remarks** element content can consist of text, JSON, or XML.

So, in order to fix the **remarks** and generate the Swagger documentation in a proper way, you must add a text after open the **remarks** tag, add a break line, and then add an example of request.

Another important detail is the indentation, you must apply a proper code indentation.

Please, find below your current scenario, a fix for your problem, and 2 examples.

**Before - Wrong (your scenario)**

```
    /// <remarks>
    ///    {
    ///     "your_val": "1a",
    ///     "member": "Test"       
    ///    }
```

[image]

**After - Correct**

```
    /// <remarks>
    /// [Description]:
    /// 
    ///     {
    ///         "your_val": "1a",
    ///         "member": "Test"       
    ///     }
    ///</remarks>
```

[image]

**Example 01:**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a Item From Query (Default)
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Sample request:
    ///
    ///     POST /api/Items/CreateViaQuery
    ///     {
    ///        "code": "0001",
    ///        "description": "Item1"
    ///     }
    ///
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param cref="CreateItemViewModel" name="createItemViewModel">Create Item View Model</param>
    /// <returns>A newly created Item</returns>
    /// <response code="201">Returns the newly created item</response>
    /// <response code="400">If the item is null</response>            
    [HttpPost("CreateViaQuery")]
    [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.Created)]
    [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
    public ActionResult<CreateItemViewModel> CreateViaQuery(CreateItemViewModel createItemViewModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        return Created("", createItemViewModel);
    }
```

[image: Example 01 Result]

**Example 02:**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a Item From Body
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Sample request:
    ///
    ///     POST /api/Items/CreateViaBody
    ///     {
    ///        "code": "0001",
    ///        "description": "Item1"
    ///     }
    ///
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param cref="CreateItemViewModel" name="createItemViewModel">Create Item View Model</param>
    /// <returns>A newly created Item</returns>
    /// <response code="201" cref="CreateItemViewModel">Returns the newly created item</response>
    /// <response code="400">If the item is null</response>            
    [HttpPost("CreateViaBody")]
    [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.Created)]
    [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
    public ActionResult<CreateItemViewModel> CreateViaBody([FromBody]CreateItemViewModel createItemViewModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        return Created("", createItemViewModel);
    }
```

[image: Example 02 Result]

For more info, please take a look the following article: 
[Get started with Swashbuckle and ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle)

I hope this can help you.